# converting date error in grails

Tags: java, mysql, date, grails

i like to show all records from my database for only passing dates(i need to pass the date),
i used grails calander 1.2.1  plugin
 in my database date is stored like   **2013-10-16 12:19:00,**
in my controller i wrote

```
println"passed date is"+params.expenseDate_value            //its prints 20/3/2013 

def result=DailyBudget.createCriteria().list()

    {
        eq("expenseDate","params.expenseDate_value")
    }
println"result"+result
```

here the **params.expenseDate_value** represents the my passing date when i print that its shows my passing date, working well. while in criteria
i got error like this
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
i think **expenseDate** getting pbm, i dont know exactly.
 how can i solve this issue. any help plz?

Comment: what is the type of `expenseDate`?

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions: Just create simple groovy class under `src/groovy` folder. With the following code.

```
class MyUtils() {
      private static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("/*date format*/")

      public static Date toDate(Object obj) {             
         if (obj) {
           return dateFormat.parse(obj)
         }
         return null;
      }

}
```

After use it in your controller.

```
def result=DailyBudget.createCriteria().list()

    {
        eq("expenseDate", MyUtils.toDate(params.expenseDate_value))
    }
```

Comment: 1) `SimpleDateFormat` isn't thread safe 2) why `"${value}"`??? 3) this code will throw exact same error, there is not change in value type

Comment: @IgorArtamonov did you try it ?

Comment: 1) it's from javadoc 3) it's basic syntax, and `"..."` means String type

Comment: ok, I see, you've modified your answer. But now it will not compile, because you shouldn't use `${}` there.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't answering, but I believe your `expenseDate` is a `Date` field. So just convert `String` to `Date`, like:

```
{
    eq("expenseDate", Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', params.expenseDate_value))
}
```